# How do I write text to a terminal line and have the user edit it? (c++)

Tags: c++, command-line-interface

I'm working on a text archiving app that runs fully in terminal using c++ and i cant for the life of me figure out how to print a line like "this is a test" and have the user edit it.

I tried searching for solutions but i couldn't find a single one.

Comment: Have a look at the [GNU Readline](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) library.

Comment: Off-topic to ask for tools/libs, and the functionality you ask for is not something trivial. Old classic would be [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses), but I guess you would be better of with some GUI tools, like QT.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ncurses`. It provides handling functions for keyboard input.

If you don't prefer to use third-party lib, you can handle ANSI escape codes for cursor movement.

Also you can easily find open source terminal editors in github and get inspire.

Comment: FYI, not all terminals or consoles support ANSI Escape Codes.